# Flexslider won't work on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery

Hi guys I recently created a custom post type for flexslider on my Wordpress theme. However upon testing it got some issues. The slider is showing up but the images wont show up on it.

There are two files I created here. slider.php and slider_post_type.php.

here's my code on the slider.php:

```
<?php

// Enqueue Flexslider Files

    function wptuts_slider_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'flex-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/slider/css/flexslider.css' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'flex-script', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/inc/slider/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_slider_scripts' );


// Initialize Slider

    function wptuts_slider_initialize() { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
              jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                direction: "horizontal",
                slideshowSpeed: 7000,
                animationSpeed: 600
              });
            });
        </script>
    <?php }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'wptuts_slider_initialize' );


// Create Slider

    function wptuts_slider_template() {

        // Query Arguments
        $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'slides',
                    'posts_per_page'    => 5
                );  

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Check if the Query returns any posts
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Start the Slider ?>
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">

                <?php       
                // The Loop
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>

                    <?php // Check if there's a Slide URL given and if so let's a link to it
                    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true ) ); ?>">
                    <?php }

                    // The Slide's Image
                    echo the_post_thumbnail();

                    // Close off the Slide's Link if there is one
                    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php } ?>

                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul><!-- .slides -->
        </div><!-- .flexslider -->

        <?php }

        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

and here's the code on the slider_post_type.php:

```
<?php

// Create Custom Post Type

    function register_slides_posttype() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Slides', 'post type general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Slide', 'post type singular name' ),
            'add_new'           => __( 'Add New Slide' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Slide' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Slide' ),
            'new_item'          => __( 'New Slide' ),
            'view_item'         => __( 'View Slide' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Slides' ),
            'not_found'         => __( 'Slide' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'=> __( 'Slide' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Slide' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Slides' )
        );

        $taxonomies = array();

        $supports = array('title','thumbnail');

        $post_type_args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'singular_label'    => __('Slide'),
            'public'            => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'publicly_queryable'=> true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'capability_type'   => 'post',
            'has_archive'       => false,
            'hierarchical'      => false,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'slides', 'with_front' => false ),
            'supports'          => $supports,
            'menu_position'     => 27, // Where it is in the menu. Change to 6 and it's below posts. 11 and it's below media, etc.
            'menu_icon'         => get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/slider/images/icon.png',
            'taxonomies'        => $taxonomies
         );
         register_post_type('slides',$post_type_args);
    }
    add_action('init', 'register_slides_posttype');



// Meta Box for Slider URL

    $slidelink_2_metabox = array( 
        'id' => 'slidelink',
        'title' => 'Slide Link',
        'page' => array('slides'),
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'default',
        'fields' => array(


                    array(
                        'name'          => 'Slide URL',
                        'desc'          => '',
                        'id'                => 'wptuts_slideurl',
                        'class'             => 'wptuts_slideurl',
                        'type'          => 'text',
                        'rich_editor'   => 0,           
                        'max'           => 0                
                    ),
                    )
    );          

    add_action('admin_menu', 'wptuts_add_slidelink_2_meta_box');
    function wptuts_add_slidelink_2_meta_box() {

        global $slidelink_2_metabox;        

        foreach($slidelink_2_metabox['page'] as $page) {
            add_meta_box($slidelink_2_metabox['id'], $slidelink_2_metabox['title'], 'wptuts_show_slidelink_2_box', $page, 'normal', 'default', $slidelink_2_metabox);
        }
    }

    // function to show meta boxes
    function wptuts_show_slidelink_2_box()  {
        global $post;
        global $slidelink_2_metabox;
        global $wptuts_prefix;
        global $wp_version;

        // Use nonce for verification
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="wptuts_slidelink_2_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

        echo '<table class="form-table">';

        foreach ($slidelink_2_metabox['fields'] as $field) {
            // get current post meta data

            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

            echo '<tr>',
                    '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', stripslashes($field['name']), '</label></th>',
                    '<td class="wptuts_field_type_' . str_replace(' ', '_', $field['type']) . '">';
            switch ($field['type']) {
                case 'text':
                    echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" /><br/>', '', stripslashes($field['desc']);
                    break;
            }
            echo    '<td>',
                '</tr>';
        }

        echo '</table>';
    }   

    // Save data from meta box
    add_action('save_post', 'wptuts_slidelink_2_save');
    function wptuts_slidelink_2_save($post_id) {
        global $post;
        global $slidelink_2_metabox;

        // verify nonce
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wptuts_slidelink_2_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // check autosave
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // check permissions
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        foreach ($slidelink_2_metabox['fields'] as $field) {

            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

            if ($new && $new != $old) {
                if($field['type'] == 'date') {
                    $new = wptuts_format_date($new);
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
                } else {
                    if(is_string($new)) {
                        $new = $new;
                    } 
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);


                }
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
            }
        }
    }
```

i already registered this on my functions.php file:

```
// Create Slider Post Type
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/slider/slider_post_type.php' );
// Create Slider
require( get_template_directory() . '/inc/slider/slider.php' );
```

here's what it looks like on the backend:
[image]

Now when I run it on my index.php here my code:

here's the output I am getting:

[image]

Any idea why does the images won't show up?

Comment: Maybe you have not set up the images for the sliders? In your screenshot of the slider edit screen, I don't see a selected image in the "Featured Image" Box.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are following the tutorial from tutsplus ["Slider to Your WordPress Theme"](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-a-responsive-jquery-slider-to-your-wordpress-theme--wp-27914)

Coding looks correct but as @cybmeta already mentioned in the comment you need to set [Featured Image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) for each slide to display in the slider properly.

Details for [Featured Image here also](http://en.support.wordpress.com/featured-images/)

Answer (score 1):

Image is not showing because you are placing image url inside meta_key `wptuts_slideurl` and not as featured image.

replace this

`echo the_post_thumbnail();`

to

```
$slideImage = get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true);
echo '<img src="'.$slideImage.'"/>';
```